# que imprime este console.log?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual seria la respuesta a este ejercicio?es java. según yo es:

```
=>5
=>7
=>9
```

esta bien mi predicción?

Comment: for (let i = 3; i < 9; i+=2) {
  console.log(i)
}
Resultado será:  3, 5 y 7...

Comment: me confundo porque no se si poner las 3 respuestas (5,7,9) o solo se muestra la ultima(9), esta parte me confunde

Comment: es javascript ...e imprime 3 5 7

Comment: No esta mal es 3,5,7 por que empieza por 3  a la siguiente es 5, .. 7 i la ultima que es 9 al no ser mas pequeño que la comparació sale del bucle. Para que sacar el resultado que has puesto tendira que ser `for(var x=5; x<=9;x+=2)`

Comment: Si es **JavaScript**, _¿por qué no pruebas el código en el navegador?_

Comment: tienes que estudiar los `operadores logicos` en todos los lenguajes los vas a ver de una u otra forma; entonces si comparas esto `x<9` lo que evaluas son todos los numeros menores a `9` sin Incluirlo a el mismo; `x <= 9` significa que evalua a todos los numeros menores o igual a `9`; ojo que estas comparaciones tambien trabajan con numero negativos ... algo asi como la recta numerica `-3 -2 -1 0 +1 +2 +3`

Comment: Recuerda leerte https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para saber que preguntas puedes o no hacer. Esta pregunta carece de investigación y es poco relevante ya que lo pudiste haber ejecutado simplemente. Y para los demás, tengan en cuenta es un usuario nuevo, en vez de votar negativamente consideren guiarle.

Comment: Te dejo acá tambien el centro de ayuda para que le heches un vistazo

Answer (score 1):

No llegará hasta 9 porque `x` incrementará hasta `< 9`. También, la variable `x` comienza desde 3 e incrementará de 2 en 2 por el `x+=2`. El resultado sería el siguiente:

```js
for (var x = 3; x < 9; x+=2) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: como se puede ejecutar el codigo aqui?? soy nueva

Comment: Debajo del código está el botón de ejecutar.

Comment: También podrías ejecutarlo en el siguiente enlace: [https://playcode.io/empty_javascript](https://playcode.io/empty_javascript)

Comment: @LoraS Al formular una pregunta, puedes darle al séptimo icono, parece una hoja con dos signos de menor y mayor <>, pero si es algo que quieres probar, considera no colocarlo aquí, así evitas criticas y votos negativos. En su lugar, presiona la tecla F12 en tu navegador, si usas MAC presiona Option + J. Se abrirá un panel, allí en consola puedes probar y ejecutar lo que quieras.
Puedes abrirlo en cualquier sitio web, hasta en la pantalla inicial de tu navegador.
Y para dar saltos de linea presiona shift + enter, para limpiar Ctrl+L. Saludos 

Answer (score 0):

en realidad imprime **3,5,7**. Ya que trata de ir concatenando de acuerdo a `x+=2`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: entonces se imprimen las 4 respuestas? no solo la ultima?

Comment: El 9 no, no se cumpliría x<9

Comment: pero 7<9, mas 2 son 9. por eso lo puse, no se si lo que propongo esta bien

Comment: Perdón si es hasta el 7